# Analysing SpecFlow duration metrics

Tags: c#, testing, specflow

I have some SpecFlow tests that provide test output like this:

```
Given my location is set to secret
-> done: Location.GivenMyLocationIsSetTo("secret") (0.0s)
And the date today is 03 Jun 2017 15:00
-> done: Date.GiveThatTheEffectiveDateIs(2017-06-03 3:00:0...) (0.0s)
And I have selected a client with the following properties
  --- table step argument ---
  | property                  | value      |
  | SomeAttr                  | someval    |
  | SomeAttr2                 | someval2   |
-> done: Client.GivenIHaveSelectedAClientWithTheFollowingProperties(<table>) (0.0s)
And I select a currency of CAD
-> done: Currency.WhenISetCurrency("CAD") (0.0s)
Then I see the following messages
  --- table step argument ---
  | classification | message       |
  | Class1         | Hello world   |
-> done: Message.ThenISeeTheFollowingMessages(<table>) (2.9s)
```

I have noticed that for *all* of my tests, the final step is the one that takes all the time (i.e. 2.9s in above - see the bottom line - all previous steps add up to zero).

I have many thousands of test cases and they take many hours to run, which has become a problem.

- Is this normal or to be expected?
- Does this duration metric include tear-down of the test harness itself (or is it purely the code-undertest)?
- Is there any tips on how I could go about analysing that duration and breaking it down further?

Note:

- I am not using Selenium
- The entire test takes 2.9s - 100% of which appears to be in that last step

Comment: Are you using Selenium to automate the browser? Can you add the code for the step definition for the last step?

Comment: For this particular test, what was the total time spent for the test? That should help you answer whether or not the teardown of the test is included in the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could come to to getting metrics within the step was to step through the code in debug mode.

I found I was able to put breakpoints in the `.feature` file and Visual Studio would break there.  Also was able to put breakpoints in my code using the usual methods.  Visual Studio [PerfTips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2019#examine-performance-using-perftips) help indicate slow parts of the code.